# Parse Error CSS (media queries)

Tags: css

Could somebody tell me why this url:

http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0482/3981/t/3/assets/queries.css

Gets a CSS PARSE ERROR, and this URL does not:

http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0245/6825/t/17/assets/queries.css

when put it through http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

I just can not find what will be causing it. 
I'm not sure but I suspect this might be why I can not get my website to be responsive on some older smart phone devices.

Any support is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the first file, it looks like the `Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers)` media query section has no closing `}`.

Comment: That seems like the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing `#currency-switcher .currency-elements` (lines 21 and 22)